# Cannot capture client metrics with Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus

I have a newbie question.

I'm using dockprom (github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) to capture metrics from a docker-compose successfully.

Now I'm trying to monitor specific metrics from my applications using golang's Prometheus client library, but Prometheus shows my endpoint as down (0), with the message, in the targets section,

```
Get http://localhost:8090/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8090: connect: connection refused
```

However, if I navigate to http://localhost:8090/metrics I can see the metrics being exposed.

Prometheus is running in a docker-compose set of containers, while my application is running in another.

The declaration of my endpoint in prometheus/prometheus.yml is:

```
job_name: 'cloud_server_auth'

scrape_interval: 10s

static_configs:

targets: ['localhost:8090']
```

I noticed that cAdvisor was failing when not running in privileged_mode, but even after fixing that, I still can't get prometheus to consume my metrics.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance to any who might shed some light on this issue, and please let me know if you need any further information.
Adolfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Prometheus in a Docker container, then when Prometheus makes calls to other places to collect metrics, `localhost` is interpreted relative to the Prometheus container, which is to say, Prometheus is trying to collect metrics from itself.

If this is all running within the same `docker-compose.yml` file then you can use the Docker Compose `services:` name of the other container(s) as hostname(s) when configuring metric target(s).  The target containers don't necessarily need to have published `ports:`, and you need to use the port number the process inside the container is running on – if your `ports:` remap a container port to a different host port, use the *second* (container) port number, not the first (host).

This is the same setup as other service-to-service calls within the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details on the container network environment.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. I changed localhost to host.docker.internal and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture metrics in grafana on localhost:3000, please review following files:

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/datasources.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
```

`prometheus/prometheus.yaml`

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "go_application"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["host.docker.internal:8080"]
```

`grafana/datasources.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: main
    type: prometheus
    access: proxy
    url: http://prometheus:9090
    isDefault: true
```

Sample API sending metrics (in golang)

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

var hits *prometheus.CounterVec

func init() {
    options := prometheus.CounterOpts{Name: "api_hits", Help: "Number of hits per endpoint"}
    labels := []string{"endpoint"}
    hits = prometheus.NewCounterVec(options, labels)
    prometheus.MustRegister(hits)
}

func main() {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        hits.WithLabelValues("/hits").Inc()
        w.Write([]byte("This is the API endpoint."))
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/hits", handler)
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```